# opencv facial sdk support

Tags: c#, java, c++, algorithm, face-recognition

I am looking for SDK that can support face detection,recognition and cluster. we have tried [Pittpatt](http://www.pittpatt.com/), and it works pretty good, however it was acquired by google, and hence freeze the new contract. So that we have to decide to use **OpenCV** which is low risk on business, while is high risk on technique.

We would like to find company or person that provides services on OpenCV face detection.

If there are some ones are interesting with it, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I did an internship at http://cyberextruder.com/ looong looong time ago and they seem to have some sort of SDK for what you need. Take a look.

Comment: @Icarus I can't find any email address of contacter on their homepage. would you like to provide such information to me?

Comment: May be Google would open Pittpatt, like several acquired technologies ;)

Comment: @Chang: The website has contact [at] cyberextruder.com listed there.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to contact http://www.computer-vision-software.com/. They have experience with OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check this out.

It has some great features that might be helpful to you.

AForge.NET Framework

AForge.NET is a C# framework designed for developers and researchers in the fields of Computer Vision and Artificial Intelligence - image processing, neural networks, genetic algorithms, machine learning, robotics, etc.

http://www.aforgenet.com/